# How to show utf8 string in org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox

Tags: java, utf-8, swt

I am trying to invoke a MessageBox with utf8 string.
But the message displayed is not readable.

```
MessageBox msg = new MessageBox(mClient.getShell(), SWT.ICON_WARNING | SWT.YES | SWT.NO);
msg.setText("Message");
msg.setMessage(utf8String);
```

Is there any way to display UTF8 string in MessageBox?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by not readable ?

Comment: Java strings are UTF-16, so what do you mean by UTF-8 data?

Comment: probably you need to use encoder

Comment: @fxm not readable means, I see some garbled text. For example: è¼å¥

Comment: @greg-449 fixed the question. I meant to say "utf-8 string"

Comment: That doesn't help, there isn't really any such thing as a 'utf-8 string' in Java. Where did this data come from? It should have been converted to UTF-16 by the time it gets in to a string.